# list view quick action - Alert info

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, list-view, quickaction

I need to create a quick action in contact list view to execute a function and display an info alert message. 
it was not possible for me to find a way to do this in lightning component.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_set_up_lex_mqa.htm&type=5

in the link it is described that Mass action are only for Update- create.

Have any idea how to resolve this in a lightning way ?

Comment: Link provided no longer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Summer 18, I don't believe there is any way to do mass actions directly to a (Lightning) Action.

My current workaround was to create a Visualforce button, use StandardSetController to shuttle the IDs in a format for `lightning:isUrlAddressable` and `lightning:navigation` to understand and finally redirect to a lightning component (that takes up the entire page) with the new `standard__component` navigation parameter found in the [new pageReference types documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

P.S. your VF page with StandardSetController will be responsible for the redirect. You can use the [VF sforce.one navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) and create a url that `lightning:isUrlAddressable` can understand.